# Stop Hibernate from trying to re-create indexes on every startup

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, indexing

I have a schema auto-update on startup turned on. Everything goes smooth but one thing: on every startup I get the following exception for every index in my schema (and there's like a hundred of those). Apparently Hibernate either fails to detect that the index is already there or does not try to detect this at all, how do I fix this? It spoils the log file and makes it hard to notice if something really went wrong.

```
03:35:45,553 WARN  [AnnotationSessionFactoryBean:1119] Unsuccessful schema statement: create index statusIndex on Application (status)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "statusindex" already exists
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.executeSchemaStatement(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:1115)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.executeSchemaScript(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:1087)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean$1.doInHibernate(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:942)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.updateDatabaseSchema(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:935)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterSessionFactoryCreation(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:883)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:591)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is not EXACTLY a direct answer to the question since I forgot to mention I also use Spring, but still, the class we are going to replace is mentioned up there in the stack trace.

I got back to the project I've been working on when I initially asked this question a year later. The exceptions were still there, noone bothered to deal with them, but this time they were really messing up my debugging. When I opened up the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean source and looked for the #executeSchemaStatement() (which is in its parent LocalSessionFactoryBean), I discovered the following javadoc:

```
    /**
 * Execute the given schema SQL on the given JDBC Statement.
 * <p>Note that the default implementation will log unsuccessful statements
 * and continue to execute. Override this method to treat failures differently.
 * @param stmt the JDBC Statement to execute the SQL on
 * @param sql the SQL statement to execute
 * @throws SQLException if thrown by JDBC methods (and considered fatal)
 */
```

So, "Override this method to treat failures differently."

That's basically it. I've subclassed AnnotationSessionFactoryBean and overridden the method:

```
public class IndexErrorWrappingSessionFactoryBean extends AnnotationSessionFactoryBean {
@Override
protected void executeSchemaStatement(Statement stmt, String sql) throws SQLException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Executing schema statement: " + sql);
    }
    try {
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
            if (ex instanceof PSQLException
                    && sql.startsWith("create index")
                    && ex.getMessage() != null
                    && ex.getMessage().endsWith("already exists")) {
                logger.warn("Unsuccessful schema statement: " + sql + " (index already exists)");
            } else {
                logger.warn("Unsuccessful schema statement: " + sql, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And now I don't have all that rubbish in my output.